# Load Data On Scroll Down Not Working Properly Jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Using 
http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

Can not find 2nd sql file after downloading it and i have to make some changes in config.php file to display data.

Comment: actually i am not getting any error but data is not display the way it has to and scroll down not working.